# Starting a bash script from inside java that lives on after the jvm exits

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a bash script from inside java that will live on after the JVM exits.  My current attempt looks something like this:

```
String[] linCmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "\"set +m; shopt -u huponexit; nohup "
   + "myScript.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null &\""};
pb = new ProcessBuilder(linCmd);
//Other stuff to monitor and start pb
```

But I'm not seeing myScript.sh actually start up (in top or ps).  By the way, the reason for the separate bash shell is because I need the `set +m` and don't want to corrupt the original with that.  Also the `nohup` and `shopt -u huponexit` may be redundant, but I've tried it without with each alone and can't seem to get it working right.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, `linCmd = { "nohup", "myScript.sh", "2>&1", ">/dev/null", "&"};` starts the script but the script dies as soon as the calling JVM does.

Comment: Java's process management capabilities are poor, as this is an inherently platform specific behavior.  I recommend doing this in C or Perl.

Comment: @Amir Afghani Of course this is inherently a platform specific command... Hence the "linCmd" and yes, there is a "winCmd" version also.  Sometimes we have to deal with platform dependent behavior in a less-than-ideal tool.  Just the nature of the beast.

Comment: my point was that Java is not good at doing this, not that you should never do it.

Comment: @Amir Afghani Oh, well yeah.  Definitely not the the best tool for this, but it's what I have.  On another note, I also occasionally use the back of a screwdriver for driving a nail into drywall because it's what I have with me and it's not THAT hard.

Comment: if you agree that writing this sort of thing is not best handled in Java, whats keeping you from doing this in a language that has stronger support for process management?  Also, please refrain from making derisive comments, as it's counter productive and unnecessary, esp in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without adding the extra quotation marks around your "set +m ... &" By including the entire thing as the third element of that array, you're telling java that this whole thing is the third argument. The quotes should be unneeded, and I think they might interfere.

Comment: I think you are correct.  I just needed `linCmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "set +m; shopt -u huponexit; nohup myScript.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null &"};

Answer (score 0):

Can you just background the process, add a call to [`disown`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_disown.htm) that backgrounded process and then let the shell exit?

> `disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]`
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If no jobspec is present, and neither the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs. The return value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.